# can I exclude a DB field when selecting *

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a mysql statement that uses a left join but need to exclude a duplicate field from the second table.  Is there an easy way to do this?

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM profiles LEFT JOIN login_users ON profiles.user_id=login_users.user_id WHERE profiles .user_id={$user_id}
```

Both the profiles and login_users table have a 'gender' field but I only want the 'gender' field from the profile table.

Comment: Just list all the fields you do want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might just want to define what you actually need, instead of using a `*`. THat's kinda good practice and all.

But if you REALLY need that `*`, you can just do something like this:

```
SELECT *,profiles.gender as TheRealGenderINeed 
FROM profiles 
   LEFT JOIN login_users ON profiles .user_id=login_users.user_id 
WHERE profiles .user_id={$user_id}
```

Now you've got an extra genderfield available as `TheRealGenderINeed`. If you don't want extra fields you should really just specify what fields you want from each table. That way you'll only get one gender if you only specify one ;)